# SecItemCopyMatching returns errSecItemNotFound

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

Communicating with a REST API and saving API token in iOS's keychain. But the keychain code is throwing a `nil` error.

KeychainAccess.swift:

```
public class func passwordForAccount(account: String, service: String = "keyChainDefaultService") -> String? {
    let queryAttributes = NSDictionary(objects: [secClassGenericPassword(), service, account, true], forKeys: [secClass(), secAttrService(), secAttrAccount(), secReturnData()])

    var retrievedData: NSData?
    var extractedData: AnyObject?
    let status = SecItemCopyMatching(queryAttributes, &extractedData)

    if (status == errSecSuccess) {
        retrievedData = extractedData as? NSData
    }
    let password = NSString(data: retrievedData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    return (password as! String)
}
```

In the above code, `retrievedData` is nil. If I do `print(status)`, I get `-25300`. This function is being called from a view controller:

```
// check if API token has expired
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
let userTokenExpiryDate : String? = KeychainAccess.passwordForAccount("Auth_Token_Expiry", service: "KeyChainService")
let dateFromString : NSDate? = dateFormatter.dateFromString(userTokenExpiryDate!)
let now = NSDate()
```

I am not sure where I'm going wrong here. Any pointers?

Comment: Well, did you actually save the password before trying to read it?

Comment: Yes, the info it's trying to read is saved/updated when a user signs in. I was able to sign in fine (meaning the tokens were saved), but as soon as I hit the new viewcontroller (after signing in), it throws the nil error.

Comment: "able to sign in" and "tokens were saved" are two very different things. From the error you have given it seems nothing was saved. Maybe `account` or `service` are different when serving? E.g. different lowercase/uppercase letters?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mDr44kUW <-- that is the code that runs when signing in. I would hope that it's running successfully and the tokens are being saved in the keychain. But if this isn't being saved, then I see why there is a problem.

Comment: Did you find a way to make it work? My SecItemCopyMatching function also returns 25300 for only iphone 13 pro max

Answer (score 0):

```
    var extractedData : AnyObject?;
    let status = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&extractedData) {
        SecItemCopyMatching(queryAttributes, UnsafeMutablePointer($0))
    }
```

Try doing it like this,  this is how I had to get it working